# AJAX call to MVC controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am new to MVC programming.I am working on a simple POC application that displays/edits data from Database.

I have 2 views and 2 controllers. On one of them the JQuery AJAX call to MVC controller action method is working fine. But not on the other one (In here, the AJAX call is not triggering the Action method).

Can anyone had this situation before???

The JQuery code is below:

```
$('#ddlZones').change(function () { 
    var value = $('#ddlZones option:selected').val(); 
    // alert(value); var status = $('#ddlStatus option:selected').val(); 
    // alert(status); $('#lstResources').children().remove();   
    $('#lstBeds').children().remove(); 
    $.ajax({ url: 'FillResources', type: 'POST', 
        data: JSON.stringify({ ZoneId: value }), 
        dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json', 
        success: function (result) { 
            for (var r in result) { 
               $('#lstResources').append('<option value="' + result[r].Value + '">' + result[r].Text + '</option>'); 
            } 
        } 
    });
});
```

---

Thanks
Latha

Comment: umm, could you show some code where the problem is happening? Or atleast the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error.The AJAX post method is not calling the Action method.Please look at my updated question for code.

Comment: I caught the exception in error: in AJAx call, it is simply saying error:'Requested URL not found'.

Comment: that means it cannot locate the `FillResources` action on the server. Try specifying both the controller and the action like this `Controller/FillResources` in the url.

Comment: I changed the URL and i got this exception 'Invalid JSON primitive: ZoneId' in Firebug. using JSON.stringify, i formatted the data.Now there is no error and doing nothing.

Comment: huh, finally AJAX call is triggering action methods. Thankyou all.

Comment: What HTTP error code you are getting on client side? Can you show code for controller action method? Make sure you have HTTP POST attribute on action method

Answer (score 0):

Check the `controller url` is called or not,
Also in `data parameter` you can call it simply like `{ ZoneId: value }` instead of
`JSON.stringify({ ZoneId: value })`,

At server side `get` this parameter by using `$_POST` if you are using **PHP**
in `controller`, also check in `console` that, you are getting `json` from `server side` or not.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'FillResources', type: 'POST', 
    data:{ ZoneId: value }, 
    dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json', 
    success: function (result) { 
        for (var r in result) { 
           $('#lstResources').append('<option value="' + result[r].Value + '">' + result[r].Text + '</option>'); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the request and the response in the browser. You can use the inbuilt ones in IE/Chrome/FF(Firebug) or fiddler. It probably is just a routing issue if this is ASP.NET MVC.

Specifically, look for what your request url is and what is the HTTP response from the server.

It is always a good practice to specify both the controller and actions in the routing urls to avoid any such errors.

Another thing to check will be if the change function is actually being called? You can put a console.log before the ajax request to make sure that this is not the case.